# Foundation Orbit not working with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I'm having problems getting Foundation orbit to work.  I can call it from regular HTML and it works fine but when I try to use dynamically generated Handlebars HTML, it does not load.

The page is here: http://danheidel.github.io/resume-foundation/#art-contact
The non-functional Orbit carosel is above, the functioning one is at the bottom of the page.  (formatting on the latter is a bit screwy since it's not in the Foundation grid)
Source is here: https://github.com/danheidel/resume-foundation

I'm not seeing any errors on load so I suspect that Orbit is not firing on the dynamically templated HTML.  Has anyone gotten Orbit to work with templating?

The dynamically generated HTML from Handlebars is below.  As far as i can tell, it's all formatted properly.

**EDIT:** I'm almost certain that Orbit is not firing because it doesn't intercept HTML changes after the initial page load.  I tested by having JQuery post-load modify a div with the proper HTML and Orbit did not intercept that either.  Can anyone tell me how to get Orbit to fire post-load?

```
      <div class="panel" id="minor-panel">
           <h3>Contact</h3>
           <ul data-orbit="">
                 <li>
                    <img src="img/contact part3_lbox.jpg">
                    <div class="orbit-caption">caption 1</div>
                 </li>

                 <li>
                    <img src="img/contact part4_lbox.jpg">
                    <div class="orbit-caption">caption 1</div>
                 </li>

                 <li>
                    <img src="img/contact part5_lbox.jpg">
                    <div class="orbit-caption">caption 1</div>
                 </li>

                 <li>
                    <img src="img/contact part6_lbox.jpg">
                    <div class="orbit-caption">caption 1</div>
                 </li>
           </ul>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, poor showing Stack Overflow. :(
Anyhow, I dug through the JS and found the answer.  Just make a call to:

```
Foundation.libs.orbit.init();
```

after each HTML update and it will properly format the slider.